# How can I get multiple arrays added to an empty array instead of just the final array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to append arrays to an empty array, but I am only getting the output of the last array added to the empty array. How can I get all the arrays appended to the new array?

code:

```
import numpy as np

def solution(a):
  na = np.array(a)
  empty_matrix = np.array([])
  for i in range(len(na)):  
    column = na[:,i]
    reverse_column = column[::-1]
    new_matrix = np.append(empty_matrix, reverse_column)
  return new_matrix
```

input:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

output:

```
array([9., 6., 3.])
```

desired output:

```
solution(a) =
    [[7, 4, 1],
     [8, 5, 2],
     [9, 6, 3]]
```

Comment: In the loop, `new_matrix` is assigned to `[] + reverse_column` every time. So you don't accumulate over `new_matrix` but kind of re-define each time. A remedy is replace all instances of `empty_matrix` with `new_matrix` (can you see why?). Another solution is `a.T[:, ::-1]` and another is `np.flipud(a).T`.

Comment: Your so called `empty_matrix` isn't "empty" .  Don't assume that arrays behave the same as lists, either with regard to "empty" nor with regard to `np.append`.  READ the `np.append` docs IN FULL before using.   Better yet, don't use it at all.

Comment: Also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your list:

```
In [111]: a = [[1, 2, 3],
     ...:      [4, 5, 6],
     ...:      [7, 8, 9]]
     ...: 
In [112]: a
Out[112]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

A well know list transpose:

```
In [113]: a1 = list(zip(*a))
In [114]: a1
Out[114]: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Now reverse each row:

```
In [115]: a2 = [row[::-1] for row in a1]
In [116]: a2
Out[116]: [(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

Doing the transpose and reverse in one expression

```
In [117]: a3 = [row[::-1] for row in zip(*a)]
In [118]: a3
Out[118]: [(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

An array equivalent

```
In [119]: A = np.array(a)
In [120]: A
Out[120]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
In [121]: A.T[:,::-1]
Out[121]: 
array([[7, 4, 1],
       [8, 5, 2],
       [9, 6, 3]])
```

Your iteration, done correctly:

```
In [122]: alist = []
     ...: for i in range(len(a)):
     ...:     column = [row[i] for row in a]
     ...:     reverse_column = column[::-1]
     ...:     alist.append(reverse_column)
     ...: 
In [123]: alist
Out[123]: [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```